# How to get previous row data in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to get the data from previous row. I have used LAG function but did not get the expected result.

Table:-

```
col1  col2  col3
ABCD    1   Y
ABCD    2   N
ABCD    3   N
EFGH    4   N
EFGH    5   Y
EFGH    6   N
XXXX    7   Y
```

Expected result

```
col1 col2 col3  col4
ABCD    1   A   NULL
ABCD    2   B   A
ABCD    3   C   B
EFGH    4   A   NULL
EFGH    5   B   A
EFGH    6   E   B
XXXX    7   F   NULL
```

Col4 should hold the data from previous row grouping by the value in Col1.
Please let me know how can this be achieved.

Comment: look up the documentation for `lag` window function.

Comment: What's your current query look like?

Comment: Makes no sense to me.  How did col3 change?

Comment: @paparazzo. Sorry. I  copied wrong data and pasted here. Col3 is same as what it was in expected result. Only col4 changes. now I got the solution from here.

Comment: @L0uis In the current query I havent used partition by col1. I have used only order by.

Comment: Fix the question and accept an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `lag()` function

```
select *, lag(col3) over (partition by col1 order by col2) as col4
from table t;
```

However You can also use `subquery` if your `SQL` doesn't have `LAG()`

```
select *,   
        (select top 1 col3
         from table
         where col1 = t.col1 and col2 < t.col2
         order by col2 desc
        ) as col4
from table t;
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this lag() and got the result

Answer (score 4):

Assuming SQL Server 2012 or newer...

```
SELECT
  *,
  LAG(col3) OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2) AS col4
FROM
  yourTable
```

If you're on SQL Server 2008 or older...

```
SELECT
  *,
  (
     SELECT TOP(1) previous.col3
       FROM yourTable   AS previous
      WHERE previous.col1 = yourTable.col1
        AND previous.col2 < yourTable.col2
   ORDER BY previous.col2 DESC
  )
    AS col4
FROM
  yourTable
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this lag() and got the result

Answer (score 1):

If you are on 2008 or earlier, try this:

```
    select t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t2.col3 as col4
    from table1 t1
    left join table1 t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 - 1 = t2.col2
```

the lag() function is the bee's knees, though. Use that, if you can.

Comment: Using `col2 - 1` is a weak assumption.  There may by rows that are out of order, discontinuities, etc.

Comment: yea, when I have to do it this way, I use a rank() and a cte. in this context, though, col2 looks like the primary key.

Comment: @James:  With Rank() you can get duplicates and gaps, use row_number() instead.

Comment: ehhh. It depends. you want duplicates and gaps, if col1 is a foreign key.

Comment: Thanks. I used this lag() and got the result. The server is new version

Answer (score -2):

Thank you all for the replies. By using the lag function with partition I got the expected result. I missed to used partition previously and due to that I was getting wrong results.