# Getting previous row Amount field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a few columns PersonID, Amount and StartDate, have provided 1 person as a sample. What I'm trying to do is
calculate the BeforeAmountCalculatedColumn automatically, basically picking up what the previous rows (by date) 
amount was. How could I do this?

```
Create Table #Results
(
    PersonID int,
    Amount money,
    StartDate datetime,
    BeforeAmountCalculatedColumn money
)

insert into #Results
(
    PersonID,
    Amount,
    StartDate,
    BeforeAmountCalculatedColumn
)
select
    1,
    '163.45',
    '30 Jan 2019',
    '202.70'
union all
select
    1,
    '202.70',
    '23 Nov 2018',
    '189.45'
union all
select
    1,
    '189.45',
    '28 Aug 2018',
    '0'
```

Comment: Look into [`LAG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get previous row data in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50489567/how-to-get-previous-row-data-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `lag()`?

```
select r.*,
       lag(amount) over (partition by personid order by startdate) as BeforeAmountCalculatedColumn
from #Results r;
```