# update value in row based on value in another row

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-9.6

I have a table with timestamped data.

```
t_stamp | col1 | col2 | col3
```

I want to update the value in say col3 based on values in col1 and col2 from the previous row in the table. By previous row I mean the row with the next lowest timestamp value. I also want to do this for every row in the table.

For example:

```
col3 = col1.prev + col2
```

Note: The operation here is only provided as an example. I want to calculate a value for col3 given a function of col1, col2 and/or previous values of either.

I was able to use a window function to create a SELECT query to give me the desired values for col3

```
SELECT lag(col1) OVER (ORDER BY t_stamp ASC) + col2 AS col3
FROM table1
```

but this does not update the values in the table. Can I somehow apply this to the original table? Or is there a way to format an update query in the same way?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to illustrate your calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the FROM clause along with the query you already have:

```
UPDATE test set col3 = prev_col1 + prev_col2
FROM (
  SELECT t_stamp,
      lag(col1) OVER (ORDER BY t_stamp ASC) prev_col1,
      lag(col2) OVER (ORDER BY t_stamp ASC) prev_col2
  FROM test) prev 
  WHERE prev.t_stamp = test.t_stamp;
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked like a charm. One clarifying question though. You said in your answer to use a 'using' clause but there is no using clause in your solution. Typo?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I fixed the text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a cumulative sum:

```
SELECT (sum(col2 + co1) OVER (ORDER BY t_stamp ASC) - col1) AS col3
FROM table1
```

Comment: Nope. The equation was only shown as an example to illustrate the result of col3 will depend on a value of another column in the previous row. This is not the desired calculation I want to perform.

Answer (score 0):

Create the first 3 columns and than use Lag to create the last col.

[How to get previous row data in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50489567/how-to-get-previous-row-data-in-sql-server)

Comment: I already used lag to calculate the values. If you read my question more carefully you will see that. The question is not how to calculate the values but how to update the table after the values have been calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sub queries.. will solve.. here is a sample

```
select col2+p_col1 from
(
SELECT col1, col2, lag(col1) OVER (ORDER BY t_stamp ASC) as p_col1
FROM table1
) t
```

Comment: I already used lag to calculate the values. If you read my question more carefully you will see that. The question is not how to calculate the values but how to update the table after the values have been calculated.